AWS error: Aws ecs fargate ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth
I am facing the below error with Fargate 1.4.0 version.
I had deployed the resources with same version earlier with all the VPC, subnet and Security group configuration. But suddenly, getting the below error.
Tried enabling the public IP. But did not work.
All DNS settings are meeting the required criteria.
IAM policies has required permissions.
Error:
Aws ecs fargate ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth
As it was working earlier and nothing changed recently wrt vpc, subnet and security group, what could be the issue and resolution for the same?

Something absolutely had to have changed for that to start happening. With the details you have provided, nobody is going to be able to help you. You need to identify what has changed. I would start by checking that all the subnets the task is configured to deploy to have the same route table.
